# How to make the timer run on certain pages using jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, timer

I have a small quiz app which uses jQuery Mobile. I'm creating a timer, which I want to run from 0 seconds until 1 hour. Though, I want the timer to run only when the user is viewing certain pages, namely only when the user is on questions. Because after answering the questions, another page with an animation appears, and then goes to another page which is the explanation. I'm displaying the timer at the header part of my questions. I have an HTML like this one:

```
<div id="q1" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Home">
                <div data-role="header"  data-position="fixed"  data-tap-toggle="false">
                    <h1><img src="images/timer.png"> <span id="timer"></span></h1>
                </div>
          <!--Here comes some other code related to the quiz question-->
</div>
```

I have 30 questions, and everyone's id starts with 'q' followed by a number, like in the example q1. And at every one's header I have that span element named "timer" where I want the numbers to be displayed.

```
        var timestamp;
        var interval = 1;
        var initTimer = true;
        var timerEl = $('span#timer');
        var qNumber;
        var qCorrect;
        var qFalse;

        function relocateTimer(newEl) {
            timerEl.prependTo(newEl);
        }

        function pad(n) { return ("0" + n).slice(-2); }

        Number.prototype.pad = function (len) {
            return (new Array(len+1).join("0") + this).slice(-len);
        }

        $(document).on("pagechange", function(event, ui) {
            if (($.mobile.activePage[0].id != "correctGIF") && ($.mobile.activePage[0].id != "wrongGIF")) {
                page = $.mobile.activePage[0].id;

                if (page.match(/\d+$/) != null) {
                    qNumber = page.match(/\d+$/)[0];
                    qCorrect = q.concat(qNumber, 'Correct');
                    qFalse = q.concat(qNumber, 'False');
                }

                if (page !== qCorrect || page !== qFalse) {
                     if (page == "q1") {
                         timestamp = new Date(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                         if (initTimer) {
                            setInterval(function() {
                                timestamp = new Date(timestamp.getTime() + interval * 1000);
                            document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = timestamp.getMinutes().pad(2) + ':' + timestamp.getSeconds().pad(2);
                            }, Math.abs(interval) * 1000);

                            initTimer = false;
                         }
                     }
                }
          }
```

I have a code like the above. I want the timer to be reseted when the user is at quesiton 1 (q1). When he/she is in other questions, from q2 to q30, I want the timer to be displayed, and continue with the time from the last left time. So, that functionality should be included inside `if (page !== qCorrect || page !== qFalse)`, but I don't know how to achieve it. Anyone, any idea?

**EDIT 1:**

As I said, I have 30 question, and they have ids between q1 to q30. I want the timer to be reseted in q1, or if 1 hour passes, it should display an alert and move to home page, which has an id home. So, my code will enter inside `if (page !== qCorrect || page !== qFalse)` only if the current active page is between q1 to q30. That's why I check there whether the current page is q1, if it is I activate the timer. So, what I understand from the answer is that, I need to do something like this there:

```
if (page !== qCorrect || page !== qFalse) {
    var curpage = '#'.concat(page);
    timestamp = new Date(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    $(curpage).on("pagebeforeshow", function(event) 
    { 
         var element = $(this).find("span#timer");
         if (initTimer) {
                setInterval(function() {
                timestamp = new Date(timestamp.getTime() + interval * 1000);
            document.getElementById(element).innerHTML = timestamp.getMinutes().pad(2) + ':' + timestamp.getSeconds().pad(2);
                }, Math.abs(interval) * 1000);

                initTimer = false;
         }
    }
}
```

Though, no idea if this is correct, and no idea how to stop the timer on pagehide event.
});

**EDIT 2:**

After your good example, I tried something for myself. I have the code below, but it doesn't seem to be working. I mean it doesn't stop the timer. After each question I show and animation whether it is correct answer or wrong (#correctGIF and #wrongGIF pages), and after that I show the answer. The point is that during those pages, the timer is not shown, which is as it must be. But when I get to the next question, instead of continuing from the previously left time, it continues from the previously left time plus 3-4 seconds more. Please note that my animations (GIFs) are each 3 seconds. Maybe the timer is active during the time that they are shown.

```
var timestamp = new Date(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var interval = 1;
var initTimer = true;
var timer = null;

function pad(n) { return ("0" + n).slice(-2); }

Number.prototype.pad = function (len) {
    return (new Array(len+1).join("0") + this).slice(-len);
}

function startTimer() {
    var currentPage = $.mobile.activePage[0].id;
    if (timer == null) {
        var $timer = $("#"+currentPage +" span#timer");
        timer = setInterval(function() { showTimer() }, 1000);
    }
}

function stopTimer() {
    if (timer !== null) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = null;
    }
}

function showTimer() {
    timestamp = new Date(timestamp.getTime() + interval * 1000);
    var currentPage = $.mobile.activePage[0].id;
    var $timer = $("#"+currentPage +" span#imter");
    $timer.html(timestamp.getMinutes().pad(2) + ':' + timestamp.getSeconds().pad(2));
    return false;
}


$(document).on("pagechange", function(event, ui) {

    $("[id^=q]").on('pagebeforeshow', function() {
        var currentPage = $.mobile.activePage[0].id;
        console.log("Current page is: " + currentPage);

        var correctIndex = currentPage.indexOf('Correct');
        var falseIndex = currentPage.indexOf('False');

        if (correctIndex > -1  || falseIndex > -1) {
            stopTimer();
        } else {
            startTimer();
        }
    });

    // I have some more code down here, checking which page is currently active and
    // acting accordingly. This part is crucial for my app.

});
```

**SOLVED:**

Seems like the timer was running during the animations, adding stopTimer(); to #correctGIF and #wrongGIF made it work. Thanks!

Comment: Check the answer again, I updated with working code.

Comment: @Floradu88 I made a new edit on the original post. Check it out please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should take a look into events from jQuery Mobile when you change the page:

http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/ in particular 'pagebeforeshow'([pagebeforeshow](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforeshow/)).

In your case 'selector' would be a class or id of the div in the question:

```
$(".selector").on("pagebeforeshow", function(event) 
{ 
     var element = $(this).find("span#timer");
     //start element animation here, start the timer
});
```

Also you should kill your timer in this function:

```
$(".selector").on("pagehide", function( event ) { ... });
```

P.S. will update the answer after the question is modified or after comments.

Jsfiddle.net example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/floradu88/sW8kv/1/

edit with code, just add this into a aaa.html and run it in browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>My Page</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <p>Hello world</p>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="star" onclick="showPage1();">Star button</a>      
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->

<div id="q1" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Home">
                <div data-role="header"  data-position="fixed"  data-tap-toggle="false">
                    <h1><img data-icon="arrow-l"> <span id="timer">Timer not started</span></h1>
                </div>
          <!--Here comes some other code related to the quiz question-->
          Question 1 - text
          <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="star" onclick="showNextPage()">Next</a>
          <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="star" onclick="showAnswerPage()">Show answer</a>
</div>

<div id="q1Answer" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Home">


                <div data-role="header"  data-position="fixed"  data-tap-toggle="false">
                    <h1><img data-icon="arrow-l"> <span id="timer">Timer not started</span></h1>
                </div>
          <!--Here comes some other code related to the quiz question-->
          Question 1 answer 
          <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="star" onclick="showNextPage()">Next</a>
</div>

<div id="q2" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Home">
                <div data-role="header"  data-position="fixed"  data-tap-toggle="false">
                    <h1><img data-icon="arrow-l"> <span id="timer">Timer not started</span></h1>
                </div>
          <!--Here comes some other code related to the quiz question-->
          Question 2 - text
          <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="star" onclick="showNextPage()">Next</a>
          <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="star" onclick="showAnswerPage()">Show answer</a>
</div>

<div id="q2Answer" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Home">
    <div data-role="header"  data-position="fixed"  data-tap-toggle="false">
                    <h1><img data-icon="arrow-l"> <span id="timer">Timer not started</span></h1>
                </div>
                Question 2 answer 
          <!--Here comes some other code related to the quiz question-->
          <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="star" onclick="showNextPage()">Next</a>
</div>

<div id="q3" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Home">
                <div data-role="header"  data-position="fixed"  data-tap-toggle="false">
                    <h1><img data-icon="arrow-l"> <span id="timer">Timer not started</span></h1>
                </div>
          <!--Here comes some other code related to the quiz question-->
          Question 3 - text
          <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="star" onclick="showNextPage()">Next</a>
          <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="star" onclick="showAnswerPage()">Show answer</a>
</div>

<div id="q3Answer" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Home">
               <div data-role="header"  data-position="fixed"  data-tap-toggle="false">
                    <h1><img data-icon="arrow-l"> <span id="timer">Timer not started</span></h1>
                </div>
                Question 3 answer 
          <!--Here comes some other code related to the quiz question-->
          <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="star" onclick="showNextPage()">Next</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var timer = null;
 var actualValue = 0;
 var questionNo = 3;

 function showNextPage(){
    var currentPage = $.mobile.activePage[0].id;

    var part = currentPage.substr(1);
    var index = part.indexOf('Answer');
    if (index > -1) {
       part = part.substr(0,index);
    }
    var number = parseInt(part);

    if (number + 1 <= questionNo) {
        var nextPageId = "#q"+ (number + 1);

        $.mobile.changePage($(nextPageId));
    } else {
       //ended questionnaire
       alert("ended questionnaire");
    }
 }

 function showAnswerPage(){

    var currentPage = $.mobile.activePage[0].id;

    var part = currentPage.substr(1);
    var number = parseInt(part);
    var nextPageId = "#q"+ number + "Answer";

    var index = currentPage.indexOf('Answer');

    stopTimer();

    $.mobile.changePage($(nextPageId));
 }

 $("[id^=q]").on('pagebeforeshow', function(){
    var currentPage = $.mobile.activePage[0].id;

    var index = currentPage.indexOf('Answer');

    if (index > -1) {
        stopTimer();
    } else {
        startTimer();
    }
 });

 function startTimer(){
    var currentPage = $.mobile.activePage[0].id;
    if (timer == null) {
        var $timer = $("#"+currentPage +" span#timer");
        timer = setInterval(function(){ showClock() }, 1000);
    }
 }

 function stopTimer(){

    if (timer !== null) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = null;
    }
 }

 function showPage1(){
    $.mobile.changePage($("#q1"));
    return false;
}

function showClock(){
   console.log(actualValue);
   actualValue = actualValue + 1;
   var currentPage = $.mobile.activePage[0].id;

   var $timer = $("#"+currentPage +" span#timer");
   $timer.html(actualValue +' s elapsed');
   return false;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just started reading about those events. Though, don't know where to exactly insert that piece of code in my example. I get that it does something just at the time of transition, when the page is becoming active. Though, I guess I don't have to repeat my setInterval code for each question.

Comment: I think you should move the code for time in the body of the above method. And make sure you destroy the old timer afterwards. I don't have environment for this, but will setup it tomorrow night and provide an example.

Comment: Now I updated the code. Is a very simple approach and will can be extended to your need. @ett

Comment: You are using a down counter, simply a countdown, and when it hits zero, you clear it. But I'm creating an up counter, so it counts up, there is no limit. Expect if it reaches 1 hour, i want to display an alert. But I want my timer to be only displayed if the current active page is between q1 and q30. If currently active page is a GIF with animation, or page showing the explanation of the answer for the question, the timer shouldn't run. So after you navigate out from q1 let's say, the timer should stop, and when you get to q2 it should continue from the previously left time.

Comment: As I said this is only an example and can be adapted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55483/discussion-between-floradu88-and-ett).